# Loading current user from database

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

So I have a table named realtimeusage it contains ID, KWH, UnitValue, AccessTIME I want to fetch usage only for the Current user by his "id" any suggestion for my code

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('connect.php');

$_SESSION['id'] = $id;

// For display  Current user realtimeusage 
$displayquery = "SELECT * ";
$displayquery .= "FROM realtimeusage WHERE `id` = '".$_SESSION['id']."'";

$displayresult = mysqli_query($connection, $displayquery);
if (!$displayresult){
    die("database query failed");
}

?>
```

the table to fetch data:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> AccountID</th>
            <th> KWH</th>
            <th>UnitValue</th>
            <th>AccessTIME</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            while ($rows= mysqli_fetch_assoc($displayresult)) {
         ?>
        <!--id-->
        <td><?php echo $rows["ID"]; ?></td>

        <!--User name-->
        <td><?php echo $rows["KWH"]; ?></td>

        <!--Full name-->
        <td><?php echo $rows["UnitValue"]; ?></td>

        <!-- Roles-->
        <td><?php echo $rows["AccessTIME"]; ?></td>

    </tbody>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

when I run this code it shows all usage in the table

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('connect.php');

$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$roles = $_SESSION['roles'];


// For display realtimeusage
$displayquery = "SELECT * ";
$displayquery .= "FROM realtimeusage";

$displayresult = mysqli_query($connection, $displayquery);
    if (!$displayresult){
        die("database query failed");
    }
```

?>

Comment: And what is the issue you are having?

Comment: it's not working I get an empty table

Comment: What is `$id` defined as..?

Comment: And you are sure `$id` is what you think it is and if you run that query manually on your database you get results?

Comment: You don't have either an `$id` or a `$connection` variable. You should also use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From where are you getting the value of id? I guess id is in $_SESSION['id'], if user is logged in, and to use that id you need to change the assignment statement as

```
$id=$_SESSION['id'];
```

And use $id in query

```
$displayquery .= "FROM `realtimeusage` WHERE `id` = '".$id."'";
```

Comment: it's still empty table :(

Comment: check if you are getting id in session... echo $_SESSION['ID'] ;